# Laravel 5: run migrations on server environment, not local

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

I have a simple set of database migrations created within my Laravel 5 application, and they run nicely on my local development environment.

Now its time to run to run the migration on my new production server environment. I have configured the DB connection and deployed the app, and the app sees the database, but there are no tables - so migrations need to be run.

The following command, I believe, should run the migrations using the "production" environment, which is set up with the remote DB connection details:

```
php artisan --env=production migrate
```

The migration works, but it runs on the local environment! Here is the environment file for my production environment(using amazon elastic beanstalk service) :

> .elasticbeanstalk.env

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=<myappname.elasticbeanstalk.com>

DB_HOST=<myapp.amazonserveraddress.amazonaws.com:3306>
DB_DATABASE=<mydbname>
DB_USERNAME=<mydbusername>
DB_PASSWORD=<mydbpassword>
```

So either my environment file is not configured correctly, or artisan is not able to switch to that environment. I could change my .env file (local development environment, named "local") to connect to the remote, production DB, but I want to properly use Laravels environments.

What am I missing? Why does the migration always run on "local"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't run any remote commands on your local `artisan`. Anything you run there will only work locally (even if you set the `ENV` variable).

Setting the `ENV` variable is just to tell the application to behave as if it is *in* that environment. But doesn't tell artisan to use the remote production environment.

If you want to run commands on your production server, I suggest you look into [Envoy](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/envoy). It is a completely standalone project (and does not have to be used only with Laravel projects) and is specifically for deployment.

It is basically a thin wrapper around SSHing into your remote server and then running commands. An example `Envoy.blade.php` file on my sites might look like this:

```
@servers(['web' => 'account@server'])

@task('deploy')
    cd ~/src

    php artisan down
    git pull origin master

    composer install --no-dev --no-progress --prefer-dist
    php artisan migrate --force --no-interaction
    php artisan optimize
    php artisan up
@endtask
```

This SSHes in, puts the application in maintenance mode, pulls the new code, does the various 'new code' setups like composer install, migrate, etc. and then pulls the application out of maintenance mode.

Comment: Ah I see. Thats a shame. I can run artisan on my local machine and update the database on the remote server by manually changing the DB details in my environment file. Then one line in command line and the remote database would be created. I will look into Envoy... i'm sure its a better way to do things. But it seems to me that any environment-specific database interaction could be handled by environments. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: yes I suppose you could put different DB details into the one application, but it's not really the recommended way (first off it only really works for DB details, as you happen to be able to remotely connect to the database). But I suppose for our normal small-time purposes it's not a big deal, but obviously if you ever had multiple application servers, it would make sense for each one to deal with its own database or composer dependencies, etc.

Comment: True. It so happens that I have security permissions to access my database directly from my IP. The only other IP which can access it is that of my hosting server / instance. I will create a script using Envoy so that the hosting server is the ONLY IP able to access my database. This will stand me in good stead when  the team expands or I want to move to different locations. I set the database instance up using wifi while on a plane! I wouldn't want to have to open up IP addresses every time i travel, I might want to do more work from planes! :) I'll accept your answer, thanks for your help.