# Is laravel a folder based framework?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to ask if laravel is a folder based framework. What I mean is that if I deploy the folder to a shared host will it work just like that or do I need to install laravel in the server (where I will be using VPS or dedicated server or any server which allows installation).
Also how can I change the root directory to laravel's public folder ?
Thanks

Comment: Just try in you local first, 1. copy and paste laravel folder, 2.set db configuration and 3. run migrations , and Laravel project will run without any problem. But as you said you can install it I suggest you to install it. Also check about laravel forge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to install any thing on the server. You just have to upload your **laravel** project folder to the web directory of your server and change the database credentials.

For Ex : If your web public directory is **public_html**, just upload your files in that folder and change the database configurations in the **config/database.php** file with the one of your of database which you must have created on the server.

Comment: For running your migrations on the server environment check this link : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/envoy . Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094930/laravel-5-run-migrations-on-server-environment-not-local

Comment: also remove the .env file while uploading, if you added any db or secure info in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely deploy laravel to shared hosting, but there are issues with deployment to consider, better option is having a minimal VPS with root access,

answer for you question (Also how can I change the root directory to laravel's public folder ? ) 
either you have to play with htaccess or smylinks if your shared hosting provide support for it, or you can make sub domain and folder pointing directly to public folder, i tried in a shard hosting and end up without avail pointing the primary domain,

otherwise to point the app public in to the primary domain, , you will need to edit your virtual host file and change directory public_html/public folder which is easiest solution with a root access (like vps),

Main disadvantage of shared hosting deployment is , you cannot run the following command without sch access and artisan,composer enabled in your server on deployment, which is necessary to boost the performance of the application,

```
composer dumpautoload -o
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```